# hibernate: 'Hints not supported yet' when I try to use withHint

Tags: hibernate, quarkus-panache, entitygraph

I encountered the n+1 problem. I am trying to use EntityGraph to solve it
but I am getting "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Hints not supported yet".
i also tried to use session.setBatchSize(20) with no help.
I would appreciate any hint

````
        return Panache.getSession().flatMap(session -> {
            EntityGraph<PocketEntity> graph = session.getEntityGraph(PocketEntity.class,"employee.projects");
          
            return findAll()
                  .withHint(FETCH.getJakartaHintName(), graph)

        .list()
                .onFailure().transform(ex -> {
                    logger.error("xxxxxx",ex);
                    return PocketsErrors.INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR;
                });
    });
    }```
````